# Invalid object name space

Tags: vb.net

I made a table in SQLServer and the idea of code is to fill the blank and click `Insert` and a new user will be added to database and the DataGridView, but I got this error:

> Invalid object name 'Users'.

This error appear after I click the `Insert` button:

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP-DLGJAU3D;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True")

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        EmployeeListDataGridView.DataSource = GetEmployeeList()
    End Sub

    Private Function GetEmployeeList() As DataTable
        Dim dtEmployees As New DataTable
        Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbx").ConnectionString

        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.EMPLOYEES", conn)
                conn.Open()
                Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                dtEmployees.Load(reader)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return dtEmployees
    End Function

    Private Sub BTN_INSERT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_INSERT.Click
        Dim command As New SqlCommand("insert into Users(Fname, Lname, age) values('" & TextBoxFN.Text & "','" & TextBoxLN.Text & "'," & TextBoxAGE.Text & ")", connection)
        connection.open()

        If command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("New User Added")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("User Not Added")
        End If
        connection.close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: in your button click, where is your `connection` coming from? Its not wrapped in a using statement...  Also, DO NOT, i repeat, Do.....NOT... do insert statements that way... Use whats called "parameterized sql"... you are opening yourself up to sql injection issues.  if you google,  "sql server invalid object name" there are quite a few options to try.

Comment: More than likely there is no `Users` table, do you mean `dbo.EMPLOYEES` table? Just a guess as you are selecting from that table and then you have an insert method...

Comment: Also, check the connection string: `Initial Catalog=master`, more than likely you don't want to be in there...

Comment: You did such a great job with Using blocks and a local connection in the `GetEmployeeList()` function and then nothing in the button event. Don't show message boxes with a connection open. The user could have gone to lunch and there sits your connection. Actually, it will probably time out but meanwhile you are tying up a connection for nothing.